# Mongo: fetch data as data tree

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection of category items in a hierarchical structure defined by category_id field. I have a requirement of fetching all these categories maintaining a tree structure based on the category_id.

---

Mongo Collection details:

category collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fca496b61e8a83e5cd0fb01"),
    "category_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Books",
    "parent_category" : null,
    "child_categories" : [ 
    {
        "category_id" : "20",
        "name" : "Action & Adventure"
    }, 
    {
        "category_id" : "48",
        "name" : "Arts, Film & Photography"
    }
     ],
     hierarchy: "Books"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fca496e61e8a83e5cd0fb30"),
    "category_id" : "48",
    "name" : "Arts, Film & Photography",
    "parent_category" : "1",
    "child_categories" : [ 
    {
        "category_id" : "69",
        "name" : "Architecture"
    }
    ],
    "hierarchy" : "Books >> Arts, Film & Photography",
    "parent_category_name" : "Books"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fca497061e8a83e5cd0fb45"),
    "category_id" : "69",,
    "name" : "Architecture",
    "parent_category" : "48",
    "child_categories" : [],
    "hierarchy" : "Books >> Arts, Film & Photography >> Architecture",
    "parent_category_name" : "Books"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fca497061e8a83e5dd0fb45"),
    "category_id" : "20",,
    "name" : "Action & Adventure",
    "parent_category" : "1",
    "child_categories" : [],
    "hierarchy" : "Books >> Action & Adventure",
    "parent_category_name" : "Books"
}
```

Trying to convert these collection records to a single array with a nested tree structure of entries as below, preferably in a single query due to performance considerations.

```
[
  {
    "category_id": "1",
    "name": "Books",
    "parent_category": null,
    "children": [
        {
        "category_id": "48",
        "name": "Arts, Film & Photography",
        "parent_category": "1",
        "children": [
            {
            "category_id": "69",
            "name": "Architecture",
            "parent_category": "48",
            "children": []
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category_id": "20",
        "name": "Action & Adventure",
        "parent_category": "1",
        "children": []
    }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: yes it does, thank you for the response @turivishal

Comment: was prepared [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r1hH-KER_DU) for your question, would be helpful.

Comment: went through that. it was really helpful, saved a whole lot of time. there were a few tweaks to be made but this was what I was exactly looking for. cheers